# Resumable Uploads Sample cannot be found for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I need to use Resumable Uploads sample for uploading large files on Youtube using V3.

I couldn't find any samples for .NET on V3. Is there anybody that has the Resumable Uploads sample?

There is a sample for PHP but it doesn't work for .NET as you know.

I found a link on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests that takes me to the Moma page but i cannot access it.

Thank you.